# Given a new proof system N show that...

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, proof-theory

Defining the new proof system $N$ as this:
We have 2 Axioms - 
$$A \rightarrow (A \lor B)$$
$$A \rightarrow (B \rightarrow A)$$

A new deduction rule:
$$\bullet \frac{(A \rightarrow B)}{A \rightarrow (A \rightarrow B)}$$

We need to proof or disproof (formally):

$I)$ The statement $\alpha \rightarrow \alpha$ is a sentence in this system (basically showing that $\vdash_N \alpha \rightarrow \alpha$)

Now for the question itself is how do I prove this formally?
I get the fact that I am always forced to have at least two logical connectives but how do I show that?

Comment: All questions should have the question *in the post*. Mentioning it in the title is redundant. Why not start with "[This is the title]" before the actual title, too?

Comment: Made a small mistake writing the deduction rule, fixing it up now

Comment: You prove _by induction_ (by induction on the length of a proof) that every theorem contains at least two connectives.

Comment: Hmm. I suppose officially there's an induction somewhere, but here in the induction you'd never need the induction hypothesis. It's entirely trivial: Every line in a proof is either an axiom or a consequence of a previous line by the deduction rule;  hence every line in a proof contains at least two connectives. (It sounds like you understand that, it's not clear why you don't think simply saying that is enough.)

Comment: I would say it relates to my lecturer sometimes telling us that simply saying stuff isn't enough and sometimes it is so I guess I kind of lost confidence in when I can and when I cant. Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: Whether or not  simply saying stuff is enough depends on how clear it is that the stuff is _true_.

Comment: You say you have "a new deduction rule" (which actually appears to be a rule of inference).  Can you also use "old deduction rules", and if so, which?

Answer (score 0):

lets define $n(A)$ as the number of connectives in  formula $A$.
By induction on the length of proof in $\mathsf{N}$ we show that if $\vdash_\mathsf{N} A$, then $n(A) \geq 2$.
If $A$ is an axiom, then it is either $A \rightarrow (A \lor B)$ or it is $A \rightarrow (A \rightarrow B)$. note that $n(A \rightarrow (A \lor B))=n(A \rightarrow (A \rightarrow B))=2n(A) + n(B) +2$ which is $\geq 2$. If $A$ is a theorem which is not an axiom, then it is derived by the rule. So $A$ is of form $B \rightarrow (B \rightarrow C)$, where $\vdash_\mathsf{N} B \rightarrow C$. So by induction hypothesis we have $n(B\rightarrow C) \geq 2$, hence $n(A)\geq 3$. qed.
Now because $n(p \rightarrow p)=1$ for atomic $p$, $\quad\nvdash_\mathsf{N} p \rightarrow p$.

Here I supposed that the system is given by axiom-schemes. You could argue similarly when we have substitution is present as a rule of inference and axiom are given as formulas.